# What is the mistake in this MySQL partition query?

Tags: mysql

Please could you tell me the problem with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE 
    `phar_bills`
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS (YEAR(bill_date))
( 
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2014), 
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2015), 
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2016), 
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2017), 
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2018), 
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2019), 
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2020), 
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2021), 
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (2022), 
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2023), 
    PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (2024), 
    PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (2025), 
    PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (2026), 
    PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (2027), 
    PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (2028), 
    PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN (2029), 
    PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (2030)
)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(pharmacy_code) 
( 
    PARTITION phar1 VALUES IN('1'), 
    PARTITION phar2 VALUES IN('2'), 
    PARTITION phar3 VALUES IN ('3')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the word `COLUMNS` between `RANGE` and the partitioning expression?

```
    BY RANGE COLUMNS (YEAR(bill_date))
             ^^^^^^^
```

What the plastic is that doing there? I don't believe that's valid syntax, but maybe you're running a newer version of MySQL.

`YEAR(bill_date)` is an expression, not the name of a column.

According to the MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual:

```
"RANGE COLUMNS does not accept expressions, only names of columns."
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-range.html

---

But if that's not valid syntax, we'd fully expect MySQL to throw an error, most likely, a "#1064 You have an error in your syntax".

Aside from that, there are all sorts of other possible issues... but we'd expect most of those to also throw an actual MySQL error message. "partitioning not enabled", "storage engine doesn't support partitioning", "foreign keys not supported on partitioned tables", or some such.